# How to create a map of records from a javascript raw object with Immutable.js?

Tags: javascript, immutability, immutable.js, reviver-function

I'm new to immutable.js and I'd like to understand better how to use records starting from a raw JS object.

With `Immutable.fromJS()` I can create a map passing a raw object, for example:

```
var images = {
   "1": {
    id: "1",
    urls: ["/medium/1.jpg", "/large/1.jpg"]
   },
   "2": {
    id: "2",
    urls: ["/medium/1.jpg", "/large/1.jpg"]
   }
  }

var imagesMap = Immutable.fromJS(images);
```

`imagesMap` is now a map containing other maps, one for each image.

I'd like instead to create a map containing records, for example using a `Image` record defined as:

```
var ImageRecord = Immutable.Record({ id: undefined, urls: undefined })
```

How can I have `imagesMap` as map of `ImageRecord`s? Is something I can do passing a reviver to `fromJS`, or should I go with the "old" approach?

```
// old approach
var imagesMap = Immutable.Map()
for (key in images) {
   imagesMap.set(key, new ImageRecord(images[key]))
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Immutable.fromJS](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS) has an optional second parameter `reviver` that you can use. You just need to decide which parts of the js object you want to turn into records.

```
var images = {
   "1": {
    id: "1",
    urls: ["/medium/1.jpg", "/large/1.jpg"]
   },
   "2": {
    id: "2",
    urls: ["/medium/1.jpg", "/large/1.jpg"]
   }
  };

var ImageRecord = Immutable.Record({ id: "0", urls: [] })

var imagesMap = Immutable.fromJS(images, function(key, value) {
  // This check should be replaced by a better way to know that
  // we really want image records
  if(/^[0-9]+$/.test(key)) {
    return new ImageRecord(value)
  }
  return value
});

// Verify that it's really a record
console.log(imagesMap.get("2").toJS())
console.log(imagesMap.get("2").delete("urls").toJS())
```

http://jsbin.com/ronomibano/4/edit

Comment: Thanks, I've also found in the docs that the reviver `key` is an empty string for top objects, making even easier to check if a value should become a Record.